# query with multiple tables

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp, lamp

this query gives top 5 number of tweets, username and number of tweets thay have

```
 SELECT users.username, COUNT(tweet.content) as tweet _count
                       FROM tweets
                       INNER JOIN users 
                       ON tweets.userid=users.id
                       GROUP BY userid ORDER BY tweet_count DESC
                       LIMIT 5
```

to explain further here are the tables involved

retweets table is composed of

```
id, tweet_id, userid, date_created
```

tweets table is composed of

```
id, userid, content, date_created
```

users table is composed of

```
id and username
```

as you can see retweets use the content of the tweets table through tweet_id and user_id.

now the problem is i want a query that gives top 5 number of retweets, username and number of retweets thay have..

im kinda confused with joining several tables and i keep getting errors when i try.
THANKS FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: Can you explain retweets table little bit more, How data is stored in both tables tweets and retweets

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT users.username,count(retweet.id) as retweets 
                       FROM retweets
                       LEFT JOIN tweets
                       ON retweets.tweet_id=tweets.id
                       INNER JOIN Users 
                       ON retweets.userid=users.id
                       GROUP BY userid
                       LIMIT 5
```

Comment: im getting this error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '_count FROM tweets LEFT JOIN users' at line 1 @Praveenkalal

Comment: my problem is with the retweets @Praveenkalal. im done with displaying top 5 tweets

Comment: your code and my codes gives the same result. but what im looking is for retweets. thanks!